# How to make a non serializable subclass?

Tags: java, serialization

I would like to get your opinion/answers on whether it is possible to mark a subclass as non-serializable?

> Ex:- Class A --> implements Serializable marker interface
>        Class B --> Extends A

As per inheritance, Class B automatically is eligible for serialization. Is their a way possible to mark Class B as non-serializable?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> It's not possible for a subclass of a Serializable class to be non-Serializable.

Although you could ensure nothing in the class ever gets serialized by making every member `transient`

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can prevent it. Define a writeObject() method in the class with the appropriate signature, and have it throw NotSerializableException.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but OP wants to *mark* it not Serializable, not *prevent* it from being serialized

Answer (score 0):

@Deepan : No way to make sub class non serializable but there is a trick to make this:

```
class B extends A {
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
        throw new NotSerializableException();
    }
}
```